# Regex for finding flagged IDs

Tags: regex, pcre

Suppose you have a textfile with the following content:

```
  X12              IK               888T
  G                I5J              P9
  544T             ZUK              ONI
 E6U5 Z339988      T8               N55
  886            W 9ZT              T95
```

Each of the elements is representing a unique ID which can be 1 to 4 items long where each items can be a character or number like shown above. The single elements are separated by a unknown number of spaces.

Now to the tricky part: There are two flags (E and W) which will occur in front of each ID. When the flag F is raised for a ID, the ID will have a E in front of it followed by a space and then an error code consisting of a single character and 6 numbers. For example for ID `6U5` in the example with the error code `Z339988`.

It is also possible, that a ID raised the flag W. In This case the Flag will be separated with a space from the ID itself like for the ID `9ZT`.

In order to treat every ID the correct way I either need to extract 3 different Lists or at least distinct if a ID has either of the two flags in front of it. Since I'm pretty new to regex I am just able to create simple queries but not queries like this with conditions or other structures.

So to come to my question: what could be a possible regex for a single line of this file to first of all extract all IDs from the line and further distinct if a ID has a specific flag?
It would be great if this could be done using just a single regex and not using 3 different regex on the same line due to performance reasons

My first solution looked like this, which is finding the single IDs but can´t determine if it is marked with a specific flag:

```
[E|W\s](\S{1,4})\s
```

Comment: Reading your solution, I'd think that no ID can start with `E`. Are the error codes always longer than 4 characters?

Comment: Yeah, the errorcodes are always longer than 4 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an alternation to match either one of the 3 possibilities and use 2 capturing groups to differentiate between them

```
\b(?<flagE>E[A-Z0-9]{1,4} [A-Z][0-9]{6})|(?<flagW>W [A-Z0-9]{1,4})|[A-Z0-9]{1,4}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?<flagE>` Named group flagE matching

  - `E[A-Z0-9]{1,4} [A-Z]\d{6}` Match `E`, 1-4 times A-Z0-9, space, single [A-Z] and 6 digits
- `)` Close group
- `|` Or
- `(?<flagW>` Named group flagW

  - `[A-Z0-9]{1,4}` Match A-Z0-9 1-4 times
- `)` Close group
- `|` Or
- `[A-Z0-9]{1,4}` Match A-Z0-9 1-4 times
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9YAuF/1)

Another option to get multiple groups on the same line could be to make use of `\G` to assert the position at the end of the previous match:

```
(?:^(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}Z)\h+|\G(?!^))(?:(?<flagE>(E)([A-Z0-9]{1,4}) ([A-Z][0-9]{6}))|(?<flagW>(W) ([A-Z0-9]{1,4}))|([A-Z0-9]{1,4}))(?:\h+|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOXdEZ/1/)

Comment: I tried to also detect a timestamp before the ID´s but didn't get it working: https://regex101.com/r/cccHe8/1 How do I have to Change the Regex to still detect the codes with an additional timestamp at the beginning?

Comment: @JohnDizzle Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/vJJFjl/1 Is is optional or is it always there?

Comment: Yeah, the timestamp or any comparable part before the ID is always there. Thank you for the additional effort!

Comment: @JohnDizzle Another option if you want to get separated groups in a line is to use `\G` to get iterative matches. See for example https://regex101.com/r/JOXdEZ/1

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<flag>E|W\s)?(?<id>[a-z0-9]{1,4})(?<errorcode>\s[a-z0-9]{5,})?
```

should do your task. I assumed that error codes are alphanumerical like the id. Global flag for case insensitivity must be set, otherwise it's `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

- `(?<flag>E|W\s)?` -> optional flag, group named "flag"
- `(?<id>[a-z0-9]{1,4})` -> id, group named "id"
- `(?<errorcode>\s[a-z0-9]{5,})?` -> optional error code, group named
  "errorcode"

Further description and example see [here](https://regex101.com/r/CJC7NC/1)

Comment: How can I add another regex part in front of your term to handle let´s say a date or other Kind of string in front of the IDs? I was struggling just to put it in front of your solution. Here is the example https://regex101.com/r/pOiXZO/1

Comment: I updated it to get it working for the first ID, but it won´t detect the remaining two IDs https://regex101.com/r/pOiXZO/3

Comment: @JohnDizzle I cannot get that working right now, I'll return later for this.

Comment: @JohnDizzle can you try `(?<date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z)(?<rpt>(?:\s+(?<flag>E|W\s)?(?<id>[a-z0-9]{1,4})(?<errorcode>\s[a-z0-9]{5,})?)+)` ? I wasn't able to verify that this captures each id right in the resulting array or matches/groups. The result should be [date:TheDate][rpt:[[flag:E][id:6U5][errorcode:Z339988]][[id:T8]][[id:T55]]].

Answer (score 0):

Is this regular expression ok?`E\S{1,4}\s\S+|W\s\S{1,4}|\S{1,4}`

[This is a demo on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/CrTruV/2)

Comment: Your solution is working great for the flagged ones but sadly does not detect the IDs without any flag

Answer (score 0):

this for find IDs with E flag:

```
E\K\S+
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UbLFSV/1)

this for find IDs with W flag:

```
W\s+\K\S+
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UbLFSV/2)

Answer (score 0):

Using named capture groups and an if-clause to only match the error code if the error flag has been risen:

```
(?<flag>(?<e_flag>E)|(?:(?<w_flag>W) ))?(?<id>[A-Z\d]{1,4})(?(e_flag) (?<error_code>[A-Z]\d{6}))
```

This regex defines the following groups:

1. flag: Either `E`, `W␣` or not present
2. e_flag: Either `E` or not present
3. w_flag: Either `W` or not present
4. id: The id
5. error_code: The error code or not present

See the demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4IH8gc/1)

Use this regex in some method like `findAll` and then for each mach you can extract the `id` group.
If you want to test if the id is flagged check if the `flag` group is present.
If you want to check if an specific flag is set check for either `e_flag` or `w_flag` group.
If you are interested in the error code extract the `error_code` group. This is always present if the `e_flag` is present otherwise it would not match.

Note:
This is a 'find'-Regex not a 'match'-Regex. It will skip all parts that do not conform to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather go for a simpler regular expression and some programming logic (including `namedtuples` here):

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re

data = """
  X12              IK               888T
  G                I5J              P9
  544T             ZUK              ONI
 E6U5 Z339988      T8               N55
  886            W 9ZT              T95
"""

ID = namedtuple('ID', 'id flag errorcode')

def getIDs(data):
    def flag(id):
        if id[0] == 'E':
            parts = id.split(" ")
            return ID(id = parts[0][1:], flag = 'e', errorcode = parts[1])
        elif id[0] == 'W':
            parts = id.split(" ")
            return ID(id = parts[1], flag = 'w', errorcode = None)
        return ID(id = id, flag = None, errorcode = None)

    rx = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')
    ids = [[flag(id.strip()) for id in rx.split(line) if id]
           for line in data.split("\n") if line]
    return ids

ids = getIDs(data)
for id in ids:
    print(id)
```

This yields

```
[ID(id='X12', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='IK', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='888T', flag=None, errorcode=None)]
[ID(id='G', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='I5J', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='P9', flag=None, errorcode=None)]
[ID(id='544T', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='ZUK', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='ONI', flag=None, errorcode=None)]
[ID(id='6U5', flag='e', errorcode='Z339988'), ID(id='T8', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='N55', flag=None, errorcode=None)]
[ID(id='886', flag=None, errorcode=None), ID(id='9ZT', flag='w', errorcode=None), ID(id='T95', flag=None, errorcode=None)]
```